# Allow individual to edit employer organization's profile information using Joomla platform

Tags: profile, joomla, user-dashboard, organization, individual

Anyone able to help me figure a way to enable an individual to edit an organization's information?

I've setup a contribution page that is filled out on behalf of an organization with an attached individual contact form. When the user submits successfully it shows they have a relationship with that company in the "view contact - relationships" portion of civi. The contact shows having a relationship with the ability to "view and update" the related organization. However, when I setup a menu link to a profile edit form and choose the original form filled out by the individual on behalf of the organization I get an error that type is "organization" and it doesn't allow access. I've tried to work with checksums and no luck figuring out the right combo. I've also found problems utilizing the "contact dashboard" because it allows users the ability to view all of the civi backend which is a huge problem.

Any solutions? What information I'm finding is that it is impossible through Joomla to allow a frontend user/individual edit the organization's profile that was originally used to create the membership. Is that correct?

Comment: have you checked out what that employee can do via their Civi Dashboard, as that 'should' enable you to let them 'edit' their permissioned 'Employer' organisation via a Profile with fields of your choosing

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the dashboard allows entirely too much control to the user. Shows links to the backend of Civi (which I can hide with css the links.) However, I'm finding it difficult to restrict the users from editing ALL the fields such as communications for familiar or formal and frilly settings like that. I ONLY want them allowed to edit what they added during profile input. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can control what shows on their dashboard - there is a setting maybe under 'customise > display preferences' - beyond that i expected you would control eg data relating to the Company, via what fields you set in the Profile

Comment: contact dashboard should not give them access to the civi contact records directly